# Getting referer info from Paypal successful payment?

Tags: php, paypal

Let's say someone paid successfully and redirected to my "successful payment" page. Can I track the referer url by

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

I want to do this because I should show "thank you" page only if visitor comes from paypal.

Comment: Do you want to check this before they pay or after they pay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` to display the PayPal referring URL after a transaction completes and I'm taken  back to my return URL. I did try some other tests to make sure the command worked - and it did. I can get the referring URL to appear.

I did a bit of research and apparently PayPal hides that information. I'm not sure why though but I'm sure it has something to do with security - sorry.

If you're looking to verify information when someone navigates to your return page you can use Payment Data Transfer.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, they hide referer right ? I have already use successful payment url, but what if they share that url ? so that lots of people will visit and get my product for free. I asked this because I only want to show the content if users come from paypal.

Comment: To do that you can use Payment Data Transfer like I mentioned. After the payment completes PayPal returns GET information to your return page and if you use PDT you'll confirm those details with PayPal and can display the product to buyers - 
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/

Comment: The link of " Payment Data Transfer Script Generator." on the 4 th one not working. Can you please direct me how can I do it ? I just need to make sure user paid the money. Thanks. Also, Do I need to add some values on IPN settings in paypal button to achieve this ? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167271/paypal-ipn-not-updating-mysql-database)

Comment: The script generator was removed and is being replaced with something else. The code samples for PDT can be found here: https://github.com/paypal/pdt-code-samples

Answer (score 0):

Since PayPal uses **HTTPS** You can track the referrer only if You use **HTTPS** (**not HTTP**).