# PayPal IPN not updating MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, paypal, paypal-ipn

please excuse my ignorance in advance, but i'm fairly new to php, and this one has been bugging me for a while.
i'm trying to write an IPN script for an online store that sells individual items. once the payment is complete, the script will update the database and change the availability from "available" to "unavailable".
the IPN seems to work fine apart from updating the database. i'm at my wits end now as i can't see what is wrong with the script. here's what i have:

```
curl_close($ch);

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

$token = $_POST['invoice'];
$item= $_POST['invoice'];

$conn=new PDO("mysql:host=SERVER;dbname=MYDATABASE","NAME","PASS");
if ($_POST['payment_status'] == 'completed')
{
   $sql="UPDATE `tbl_products` SET `id_status` = 3 WHERE `id_product`=:idproduct";
   $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindParam(':idproduct',$item);
   $stmt->execute();
}
if ($_POST['payment_status'] == 'pending')
{
    $sql="UPDATE `tbl_products` SET `id_status` = 2 WHERE `id_product`=:idproduct";
    $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':idproduct',$item);
    $stmt->execute();
}
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $emailtext .= $key . " = " .$value ."\n\n";
}
mail("MYEMAIL", "Live-VALID IPN", $emailtext . "\n\n" . $req);
}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0)
{
// log for manual investigation
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $emailtext .= $key . " = " .$value ."\n\n";
}
mail("MYEMAIL", "Live-INVALID IPN", $emailtext . "\n\n" . $req);
}
```

Comment: You are binding the value of `invoice` to a parameter called `idproduct`. Products and invoices are different things, so maybe look into that?

Comment: hi Klaus. thanks so much for your reply. "invoice" is just a variable in the form i'm using to pass the item number(which is id_product in the database). i have just changed this to "item_number" instead and tried again but still no luck. i idid have it as "item_number" before but changed it to "invoice" to see if that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal IPN returned status have first character uppercase.

So `Completed` is not equal to `completed`. Try this

```
curl_close($ch);

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

$token = $_POST['invoice'];
$item= $_POST['invoice'];

$conn=new PDO("mysql:host=SERVER;dbname=MYDATABASE","NAME","PASS");
if ($_POST['payment_status'] == 'Completed')
{
   $sql="UPDATE `tbl_products` SET `id_status` = 3 WHERE `id_product`=:idproduct";
   $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindParam(':idproduct',$item);
   $stmt->execute();
}
if ($_POST['payment_status'] == 'Pending')
{
    $sql="UPDATE `tbl_products` SET `id_status` = 2 WHERE `id_product`=:idproduct";
    $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':idproduct',$item);
    $stmt->execute();
}
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $emailtext .= $key . " = " .$value ."\n\n";
}
mail("MYEMAIL", "Live-VALID IPN", $emailtext . "\n\n" . $req);
}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0)
{
// log for manual investigation
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $emailtext .= $key . " = " .$value ."\n\n";
}
mail("MYEMAIL", "Live-INVALID IPN", $emailtext . "\n\n" . $req);
}
```

It is better to store the status in a variable and use php `strtolower` function to make them lower case.

```
$paypalStatus = strtolower($_POST['payment_status']);
```

Than do the check like this

```
if($paypalStatus == 'pending')
```

Comment: thank you so much! you have finally solved the issue that has bugged me for ages!