# Redirect all incoming HTTP traffic to homepage except when coming from Paypal.com domain in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, http, redirect, paypal, http-referer

I want to just redirect all incoming traffic including direct address bar input to homepage for one of my Wordpress page.

Will just have to allow opening of this page if coming from paypal.com, I understand HTTP Referer can help here but please help with the correct codes.

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone ever read my post?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `HTTP_REFERER` variable with PayPal was addressed in this post: [Getting referer info from Paypal successful payment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106928/getting-referer-info-from-paypal-successful-payment)

You aren't able to capture redirect URL from PayPal so you wouldn't be able to check for that. You can try using PDT - which is also discussed in that post.